# Laravel phpunit tests Cannot find TestCase object on call stack

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-testing

where running all test
`php artisan test`
everything work as expected and all tests runs

[image]

now , when i run signle test `php artisan test --filter test_get_profile` i get this wired error

```
An error occurred inside PHPUnit.

Message:  Cannot find TestCase object on call stack
Location: D:\laragon\www\project\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\TextUI\TestRunner.php:68
```

but some other tests still work, for example, test_login and test_register works , but when i create a new test sometimes it work sometimes i get this wired error

PS: i add the file path example `php artisan test tests/Feature/AccountTest.php --filter test_get_profile` i didnt get any error , but i dont what to always include the file path

please **note that all tests are empty**

```
public function test_get_profile(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
```

anyone know the issue ?
i'm using laravel 10 and phpunit 10

phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <source>
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </source>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <!-- <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/> -->
        <!-- <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/> -->
        <env name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

UserTest.php

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_login(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

    public function test_register(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

AccountTest.php

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class AccountTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     */
    public function test_get_profile(): void
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what `tests\TestCase.php` has? Did you modify the original file?

Comment: I also experiencing it now. I'm still looking for solution.

Comment: No, i didn't change any things , it's new f fresh Laravel 10 app

Comment: I am seeing the same thing too but on an existing application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a bug in PHPUnit.

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/5403

This is the fix -

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/16166431bce84bb100d8e7fe867d612bdfe61776#diff-548ab8441af390a03ab9bf5e83a441aaa67c43de14b247a1426c2983b434bd89

Run a composer update to get the latest version.

Comment: Downgrading to 10.1.3 fixed it for me.  Thanks!

Comment: A fix has been released in PHPUnit 10.2.1, see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/10.2/ChangeLog-10.2.md

Comment: I still get this error after upgrading to 10.2.1 :(

Comment: Same problem here with phpunit 10.3.5. Did you find a solution @st-jan ?

Comment: If anyone else comes across this issue, I found the issue was with (at least for me) the `.phpunit.result.caceh` file. Once I deleted the original `.phpunit.result.cache` file and reran phpunit, it works as expected.

Comment: @PhilCross, tnx, I have a similar case. For some reason my `.phpunit.cache` had `root` as the owner & group in the Docker container, but the container itself was running under a non-root user.